# Expand/open a spinner on click of another item/widget?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to expand a Spinner when user click on another Button. as example : I have a Spinner with values and a 'OK' button when user click on 'ok' buttton without selecting any value from spinner, Spinner expands itself.
Is this possible to get a event to expand spinner without user interaction on spinner.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Just call `Spinner.performClick()` to expand `Spinner` without user interaction...

```
    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(spinner.getSelectedItem() == null) { // user selected nothing...
                spinner.performClick();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Put in your view.onClick

```
YourSpinner.PerformClick();
```