# How to show Spinner-List when we tapped on button in android?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hi I recently came to the android technology and in my app I have two buttons(one for showing movies-list and another one for showing countrieslist)

When I tap on the second button I want to display movies-list in spinner-list as in the first image bellow.

But according to my code, when I tap on the button first spinner is appearing and I selected any one item and set that to my button title but after selection spinner still visible B/w two button as like my second screen how can remove it.

How can I resolve this problem?

Please help me.

I want to show directly spinner-list when I tap on button.

### xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Button1Action"
        android:text="CountiesList"/>

    <Spinner
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Button2Action"
        android:text="MoviesList"/>

    <Spinner
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

### activity:-

```
public class spinnerListProgramatically extends AppCompatActivity{

    String [] countriesList = {"india","usa","england"
    };

    String [] moviesList = {"fury","300 rise of an empire","troy"
    };
    Spinner spinner1,spinner2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinnerlist_runtime);
    }

    public void Button1Action(View view){

        spinner1  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countriesList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void Button2Action(View view){

        spinner2  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, moviesList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

[image]

---[image]

Comment: You have two spinner and two buttons, then why aren't you initializing both at once ? I mean in `onCreate` then change the `Visibility` as required.

Comment: i am very new for android please tell user suggestions with some code i want to show spinnerlist without any userinteraction when i tappped on button

Comment: follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249380/expand-open-a-spinner-on-click-of-another-item-widget

Comment: Vivek Mishra i know how to show spinnerlist when i tapped on button but my question is not that please see clearly

Comment: Try adding `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after setAdapter and spinner1.setSelection(0); after that.

Comment: @shree Krishna please post some code  i am very new i am not understand how can i do as like what u said

Comment: @Krish Everything is working fine as you've written what do you expect actually. Can you please elaborate more.. When clicking first button first spinner is showing and after clicking second second spinner is also showing then what is the problem ?

Comment: @Krish see my answer.

Comment: are you trying to show same spinner but different data after as those buttons are clicked ?

Comment: i want to visiable only spiiner list i dont want to visiable spiiner prompts when i tapped on buttons

Comment: do you mean an empty spinner with no items inside ?

Comment: @Shree Krishna i don't won't display selectedItem in Spinner just the ListItem in want to display.

Comment: No. Really your question and your each elaborations are not clear. Do you know the exact work of spinner. It shows list prompts and shows selected items. You are telling that Don't want to display selected item but want to display listitems means nothing specific and really meaningless.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106881/discussion-between-krish-and-shree-krishna).

Comment: @Krish Hey what happened didn't you try ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not remove `Spinner` and have just a `Button` instead. Having a `Spinner` and `Button` both, makes no sense.

As per the image you have shown, you require `PopupMenu`:

```
public void Button2Action(View view){
    showFilterPopup(view);
}

private void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    // Inflate the menu from xml
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup, popup.getMenu());
    // Setup menu item selection
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.troy:
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "troy", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
            case R.id.rise:
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "300 Rise of Empire", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              return true;
            default:
              return false;
            }
        }
    });
    // Handle dismissal with: popup.setOnDismissListener(...);
    // Show the menu
    popup.show();
  }
```

Your `R.menu.popup` will contain every item you need.

This approach will be useful when you have static set of data.

With few more steps you can make it dynamic. Hope this helps.

Comment: oh u mean spinner is not correct for making my requirement?

Answer (score 5):

Use this it work

```
  public void Button1Action(View view){


        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countriesList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        spinner1.performClick();
    }

    public void Button2Action(View view){


        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, moviesList);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        spinner2.performClick();

    }
```

View this Screen

Can set this as the screen Display.

[image]

Comment: @Harsad when i tapped on button spinner is appearing  ok when i tapped on button i want to set that title to realated button using spinner listner

Comment: i want only visible spinnerList i don't want to visible spinner prompts

Comment: i hope ur understand

Comment: @Krish means you don't won't display selectedItem in Spinner just the ListItem in want to display.

Comment: i hope ur completly understand my problem can u provide solution

Comment: you want to Spinner or not ?

Comment: yes yes i want spinner,is my requirement not possible through spinner?

Comment: Make Spinner Visibility to `INVISIBLE` see my answer ?

Comment: then spinnerlist also not visiable @Hasrad

Comment: In My Display is `VISIBLE` just copy my code and paste it in your Activity.

Comment: see that screen u understand problem

Comment: see this screen that's my problem
i have already set spinner selected items as title of button then i don't want to display that spinner b/w that two buttons

Comment: put screen shot in question because I can't access google drive in my PC.

Comment: Have you tried my code That's give the Same Output as you want.

Comment: hi @harsed see my screen above

Comment: i f i set that code gap coming b/w two buttons brother

Answer (score 3):

OK, Finally I knew what you really meant to say after a long discussion. I have provided you full source codes which are optimized and modified a little bits from yours.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Button1Action"
        android:text="CountiesList"/>

    <Spinner

        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <Spinner
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"    
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Button2Action"
        android:text="MoviesList"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Your Activity**

```
public class spinnerListProgramatically extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button button1, button2;
    String [] countriesList = {"NONE","india","usa","england"};
    String [] moviesList = {"NONE","fury","300 rise of an empire","troy" };
    Spinner spinner1,spinner2;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //Your other setup codes
          spinner1  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner2  = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
}

public void Button1Action(View view){
   ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countriesList);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
     spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
     spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position!=0) {
                    button1.setText(countriesList[position]);
                    spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {    
            }
        });   
    }

  public void Button2Action(View view){   
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, moviesList);
     dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);  
     spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
     spinner2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position!=0) {
                    button2.setText(moviesList[position]);
                    spinner2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });    
}
```

Comment: Why are you ticking both one after another ?

Comment: That was alternative not your requirements. But it's ok I won't mind.

Answer (score 2):

**show Spinner-List item without tap on spinner**

```
Spinner spi_type = findViewById(R.id.spi_type);
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
imgVIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // performClick() this method show Spinner-List item without tap on spinner
                spi_type.performClick();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

cant comment cause am not having that much reputation.. can u be more specific of what you want to achieve??

The problem was that

```
   if(spinner2.getSelectedItem() == null)
```

is not null.. it by default tasks the first value

so use this code instead

```
   if(spinner2.getSelectedItem() == "fury") {
        // for checking user havent selected anything
        spinner2.performClick();
    }

  if(spinner1.getSelectedItem() == "india") {
        // for checking user havent selected anything
        spinner1.performClick();
    }
```

and for setting the title for button

```
    public void Button1Action(View view){
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, countriesList);
    dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);

    spinner1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    String s = (String) spinner1.getSelectedItem();
    spinner1.performClick();

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            button.setText(""+ spinner1.getSelectedItem());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```

in the button onCLick
and also intialize the buttons on onCreate

```
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

and placing adaptor is not an issue..

Comment: why are you adding multiple answers except editing the first one ?

Comment: @Sanoop when i tapped on button spinner is appearing  ok when i tapped on button i want to set that title to realated button using spinner listner

Comment: i want only visible spinnerList i don't want to visible spinner prompts

Comment: i don't won't display selectedItem in Spinner just the ListItem in want to display.

Comment: then i don't want to display selectedItem in Spinner just the ListItem in want to display.

Comment: @Krish Can you be more specific  of what you want to achieve?

Comment: see this screen that's my problem
i have already set spinner selected items as title of button then i don't want to display that spinner b/w that two buttons

Comment: ok.. After selection you want the spinner still there but not between buttons or Remove it from layout??

Comment: i don't want to show that spinner b/w buttons after selection

Comment: Can you grant access to Drive?

Comment: you can use the setVisiblity to Gone .. if thats you want to achieve.. :/

Comment: can u upadte using Gone property please

Comment: spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE); just below button.setText(""+ spinner1.getSelectedItem());

Comment: Hope it fixes all your issues

Answer (score -3):

[image]  find spinner and set adapetr before Button onClick method

Comment: what do u want to say i am not understand